# React - Centering markers on Vertical Timeline

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a vertical timeline where I need the circular markers to be on the center line. My issue is that the markers for the block-items on the right appear centered on the timeline, however the ones on the left do not. Instead they are to the left of the timeline date of the block items on the left. This is probably a simple fix, but I am spent on ideas at this point. Below is my ReactJS code for my Experience.js file and my App.Css file.

Timeline issue photo [image]

**Experience.JS**

```
    *import React from "react";
    const Experience = () => {
      return (
        <div id="Experience" className="experience">
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-center my-5">
          <h1>Experience</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="container experience-wrapper">
          <div className="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
            <div className="marker"></div>
            <div className="timeline-content">
              <h3>2014-2019</h3>
                <p>State Street
                  <br></br>
                  <br></br>
                  ● Coordinate with onshore and offshore teams to facilitate resolutions and present results to management.
                  <br></br>
                  ● Investigated exceptions and problems affecting accounting records or prices.
                  <br></br>
                  ● Helped to reduce risk to clients and improve efficiency through various projects.
                  <br></br>
                  ● Composed daily and weekly reports to senior management on fund activities and other operational issues.
                  <br></br>
                  ● Review of daily audit checklists from the China and India offshore teams to ensure compliance.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            {/* - */}
            <div className="timeline-block timeline-block-left">
            <div className="marker"></div>
            <div className="timeline-content">
              <h3>2019-2020</h3>
                <p>Balfour Beatty
                  <br></br>
                  <br></br>
                  ● Preparation, maintenance, and implementation of various document control entities such as daily reports, material procurement logs, submittal logs, as-builts, testing and inspection logs, RFI logs, and change order logs.
                  <br></br>
                  ● Understanding, drafting, and enforcement of contracts.
                  <br></br>
                  ● Assist the superintendent and project manager in the implementation of policies and the execution of the project.
                  <br></br>
                  ● Manage various scopes of work from numerous subcontractors.
                  <br></br>
                  ● Project management.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
                      {/* - */}
            <div className="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
            <div className="marker"></div>
            <div className="timeline-content">
              <h3>2020-2021</h3>
                <p>ITS Solutions
                  <br></br>
                  <br></br>
                  ● Assist the Inspector of Record with documentation and processing of daily field reports.
                  <br></br>
                  ● Documentation and review of contractor inspection requests.
                  <br></br>
                  ● Review of the contract documents to ensure they meet the standards specified in the California Building Code.
                  <br></br>
                  ● Perform field audits to ensure material is installed per the contract requirements.
                </p>
              </div>
          </div>
                      {/* - */}
            <div className="timeline-block timeline-block-left">
            <div className="marker"></div>
            <div className="timeline-content">
              <h3>2020-2021</h3>
                <p>Loaves and Fishes
              <br></br>
              <br></br>
                  ● Lorem ipsum
                </p>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      )
    }
    export default Experience;*
```

**App.css**

```
    *.experience {
      padding: 0.7rem;
    }
    
    .experience-wrapper {
      position: relative;
      padding: 3.125rem;
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    .experience h1 {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      color: var(--primary-green);
    }
    
    .experience-wrapper::before {
      position: absolute;
      content: "";
      top: 0;
      left: 50%;
      margin-left: -0.0625rem;
      width: 0.125rem;
      height: 100%;
      background: var(--primary-grey);
      z-index: 1;
    }
    
    .timeline-block {
      width: calc(50% + 0.5rem);
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-between;
      clear: both;
    }
    
    .timeline-block-right {
      float: right;
    }
    
    .timeline-block-left {
      float: left;
      direction: ltr;
    }
    
    .marker {
      width: 1rem;
      height: 1rem;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 0.3125rem solid var(--primary-dark-grey);
      background-color: var(--primary-green);
      margin-top: 0.625rem;
      z-index: 3;
    }
    
    .timeline-content {
      width: 95%;
      padding: 0 0.9375rem;
      color: var(--primary-dark-grey);
      direction: ltr;
    }
    
    .timeline-content h3 {
      margin-top: 0.3125rem;
      color: var(--primary-blue);
      font-weight: 900;
    }
    @media(mid-width: 786px) {
      .experience .container {
        padding-left: 0;
      }
      .experience-wrapper::before {
        
        left: 0.5rem;
        margin-bottom: 1.875rem;
      }
      .timeline-block-right {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
      }
      .timeline-block-left {
        float: none;
        direction: rtl;
        width: 100%;
      }
    }*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed my .timeline-block left direction from ltr to rtl. This has now centered the left dots to the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I would put `position: relative` on `.timeline-block` to absolute position the `.marker` to the top of that container.

Then I would position the `.timeline-block-left` to have `right: .7rem` and `.timeline-block-right` to have `left: .7rem`. That way they will always be in the center on your line.

I also made some improvements to your body and outer containers to make sure they maintain full height of the page.

Is this what you are looking for?

```css
:root {
  --primary-green: green;
  --primary-grey: gray;
  --primary-dark-grey: darkgray;
  --primary-blue: blue;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body,
.experience {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.experience-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
}

*.experience {
  padding: 0.7rem;
}

.experience h1 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: var(--primary-green);
}

.experience-wrapper::before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -0.0625rem;
  width: 0.125rem;
  height: 100%;
  background: var(--primary-grey);
  z-index: 1;
}

.timeline-block {
  position: relative;
  width: calc(50% + 0.5rem);
  padding-left: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  clear: both;
}

.timeline-block-right {
  float: right;
}

.timeline-block-left {
  float: left;
  direction: ltr;
}

.marker {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 0.3125rem solid var(--primary-dark-grey);
  background-color: var(--primary-green);
  margin-top: 0.625rem;
  z-index: 3;
}

.timeline-block-left .marker {
  right: 0.7rem;
}

.timeline-block-right .marker {
  left: 0.7rem;
}

.timeline-content {
  width: 95%;
  padding: 0 2rem;
  color: var(--primary-dark-grey);
  direction: ltr;
}

.timeline-content h3 {
  margin-top: 0.3125rem;
  color: var(--primary-blue);
  font-weight: 900;
}
@media (mid-width: 786px) {
  .experience .container {
    padding-left: 0;
  }
  .experience-wrapper::before {
    left: 0.5rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.875rem;
  }
  .timeline-block-right {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .timeline-block-left {
    float: none;
    direction: rtl;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="Experience" class="experience">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-center my-5">
    <h1>Experience</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="container experience-wrapper">
    <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
      <div class="marker"></div>
      <div class="timeline-content">
        <h3>2014-2019</h3>
        <p>State Street
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          ● Coordinate with onshore and offshore teams to facilitate resolutions and present results to management.
          <br></br>
          ● Investigated exceptions and problems affecting accounting records or prices.
          <br></br>
          ● Helped to reduce risk to clients and improve efficiency through various projects.
          <br></br>
          ● Composed daily and weekly reports to senior management on fund activities and other operational issues.
          <br></br>
          ● Review of daily audit checklists from the China and India offshore teams to ensure compliance.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    {/* - */}
    <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-left">
      <div class="marker"></div>
      <div class="timeline-content">
        <h3>2019-2020</h3>
        <p>Balfour Beatty
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          ● Preparation, maintenance, and implementation of various document control entities such as daily reports, material procurement logs, submittal logs, as-builts, testing and inspection logs, RFI logs, and change order logs.
          <br></br>
          ● Understanding, drafting, and enforcement of contracts.
          <br></br>
          ● Assist the superintendent and project manager in the implementation of policies and the execution of the project.
          <br></br>
          ● Manage various scopes of work from numerous subcontractors.
          <br></br>
          ● Project management.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    {/* - */}
    <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-right">
      <div class="marker"></div>
      <div class="timeline-content">
        <h3>2020-2021</h3>
        <p>ITS Solutions
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          ● Assist the Inspector of Record with documentation and processing of daily field reports.
          <br></br>
          ● Documentation and review of contractor inspection requests.
          <br></br>
          ● Review of the contract documents to ensure they meet the standards specified in the California Building Code.
          <br></br>
          ● Perform field audits to ensure material is installed per the contract requirements.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    {/* - */}
    <div class="timeline-block timeline-block-left">
      <div class="marker"></div>
      <div class="timeline-content">
        <h3>2020-2021</h3>
        <p>Loaves and Fishes
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          ● Lorem ipsum
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This did not solve my issue, but I do appreciate the response.

It was actually quite an easy fix and I feel dumb for overlooking it. I needed to change my .timeline-block left direction from ltr to rtl. This has now centered the left dots to the middle.